# How to reload an image (which failed to load) without refreshing the page on chrome on Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, images

On a certain webpage, when the website is really busy, an image sometimes fails to load.

When it happens on chrome on a laptop (windows), and I right-click on the icon/image which appears instead of the actual image, an option to "reload image" appears in the menu.

But when it happens on chrome on android, and I "long-click", the menu which appears doesn't have that "reload image" option. Which means that the only option left is to refresh the whole page. (Just assume that we only need to reload the image and not refresh the whole page)

Is there a way to have that "reload image" option in the chrome for android, just as it is there in chrome for windows? Or someway to just reload the image which failed to load without refreshing the whole page?

Comment: Chrome for Android cannot be customized at all. So if it offers no relevant context-menu option (and there is no relevant chrome flag either) then nothing you can do about it. One solution is to use Kiwi Browser which is Chrome based but allows loading Chrome extensions. A simple search led me to a "[Reload Images](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reload-images/mmpkgaclonhcgcmhladojjaindogpacc)" extension. If you install this extension in Kiwi Browser, then per its description it would add a context-menu entry that you're looking for.

Comment: @Firelord Thanks a lot. I will try that.

Comment: @Firelord Update: I tried that extension on Kiwi and Yandex on android and it doesn't work. But it works fine on chrome on a laptop. In Kiwi, the "reload image" option doesn't even appear after installing the extension. On Yandex (android), the option appears but nothing happens on clicking it. Thanks a lot for that anyway.